# I got the problem with AJAX request (OctoberCMS)

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, webpack, octobercms

Laravel / OctoberCMS
$.request is not a function

I got a problem with with AJAX request inside file 'dist/app.js' (created by webpack).

```
app.js file:
import 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap';

$(function () {
$.request('Cart::onAdd', {
'update': {'cart-items': '.cart-item-wrapper'}
});
});
```

that throws an error:
jQuery.Deferred exception: $.request is not a function TypeError: $.request is not a function
at HTMLDocument. (http://localhost/dental/combine/b71d14df8c4d4ddba2c49a7f4750930f-1567079039.js:1232:5)
at mightThrow (http://localhost/dental/combine/b71d14df8c4d4ddba2c49a7f4750930f-1567079039.js:9406:29)
at process (http://localhost/dental/combine/b71d14df8c4d4ddba2c49a7f4750930f-1567079039.js:9474:12) undefined

when i put this in html file (layout.htm)

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ [
        '@jquery',
        '@framework',
        '@framework.extras',
        'assets/dist/js/app.js',
        ]|theme }}.js">
    </script>
    {% scripts %}
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $.request('Cart::onAdd', {
                'update': {'cart-items': '.cart-item-wrapper'}
            });
        });
    </script>
```

it works correct

{% put script %} also works correct

The problem is with the file generated by webpack

Jquery in webpack is fine

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to first `import` the `$` jquery first?

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

If this doesn't work, try to add this to your webpack configuration:

```
externals: {
   jquery: 'jQuery'
}
```

Comment: webpack.mix.js 
laravel-mix

i got this in my webpack: 

mix.autoload({
  jquery: ['$', 'window.jQuery']
});

jquery works correct in the rest of page

Comment: @gorny_dev So you are sure `$` in your code is not `undefined`?